# Array with jQuery .get

Tags: jquery, arrays, getjson

```
var website = ["http://url.com", "http://ebay.com"]
var array = [];

$.get(website, function(sourcecode) {
    array = sourcecode;
});

console.log(sourcecode);
```

I need to get the **sourcecode** variable to the combined sourcecode of all the websites within the **website** variable. Unfortunately, an array does not work with .get. Any clue as to how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Loop the website property and push the result to the array

```
var website = ["http://url.com", "http://ebay.com"]
var array = [];

for (var i=0;i <website.lenght;i++){
    $.get(website[i], function(sourcecode)   {
        array.push(sourcecode);
    });
}

console.log(sourcecode);
```